# Auto assigning 777 to files created

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions

```
sudo rm -rf app/logs
sudo mkdir app/logs
sudo chmod -R 777 app/logs
```

This is what I do but the problem is when a file gets created behind the scene by any program,  web application or a behat test, the file doesn't automatically get 777 permission assigned to it. They rather get 644. That's my problem. What am I missing?

I've checked these:

- [Set file permissions so that new files inherit same permissions](https://superuser.com/questions/264383/set-file-permissions-so-that-new-files-inherit-same-permissions)
- [How to make new file permission inherit from the parent
  directory](https://superuser.com/questions/151911/how-to-make-new-file-permission-inherit-from-the-parent-directory)

Comment: What have you changed to try to get this to work ?  Did you create an ACL per the second answer ?

Comment: To be honest, when it comes to reading some answers (which requires more knowledge about *nux environment than I have), I get confused. I'm very very basic user of Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose any of the three methods

1. Use `mkdir -m 777 app/logs`
2. Create a script

   **#!/bin/bash**

   **sudo mkdir -m 777 $1**

So exectute ./script_name.sh app/logs